# Meaning of SNMP V2 Traps and way to customize it

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

Recently I am facing a problem with SNMP Trap generation. I have already configured my SNMP Trap and if any error occurs in hard disk I am getting the below trap.

> Trap Type = -89 Variables = [1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = 0:00:00.16,
>   1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = 1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.0.1, 1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.1.0 = Hard disk status, 1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.2.0 = , 1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.3.0 =
>   , 1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.4.0 = 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.100.1,
>   1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.5.0 = 1, 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.2.1 = /, 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.101.1 = /: less than 99% free (= 79%)]

Now for project purpose I need to know the meaning of every OI for my project purpose like whats is the meaning form 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = 1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.0.1 mentioned in the trap. So, where I will find those. I have done googling but details of few OID's are not present.

Secondly, my client wants to customize the trap as per their requirement. So, how could I achieve that. I am new to SNMP so, please clarify me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! It looks like you need start with the basics. This is a decent introduction to how OIDs work. http://www.networkmanagementsoftware.com/snmp-tutorial-part-2-rounding-out-the-basics

Comment: As per the article if any hardware send custom traps(like CISCO) that should be intimated to the NMS through MIB file. But the question is, how I can modify the the traps send to the NMS from the Hard disk installed in the server? Only changing the MIB file of the server will not change the trap.. Ami I right?

Comment: You're right, changing the MIB on the Manager does nothing. In fact, you shouldn't do that because the MIB is supposed to be an immutable specification from the MIB vendor. Only they can change it (by issuing a new version). Surely, the Net-snmp documentation must cover how to change the contents of outbound traps?

Comment: Is it mean that I can not change the structure of a vendor specific traps?

Comment: That means I can not change the vendor specific traps according to my need. But I also have a custom OID with the trap format provided by my company, functionality of this trap is to check a server program(Server check program is written in C). Now how could I generate the MIB for that OID(As it's in a certain format) and how to map the server checking program  with the MIB request.